# Calculate new gradient positions after the polygon it fills changes dimensions

Tags: php, javascript, math, vector, svg

**What I want to do?**

Updates to this question: 7/10/2012 - "gradientTransform not quite" Inspired by Duopixel
7/11/2012 - "SVG Code from the example" 7/16/2012 - "@dignifiedquire take on this problem"

I'm trying to create a tool that let's the user dynamically resize polygons. Most of the polygons are filled with gradients `fill="url(#top_surface_1_gradient)"`. The way I go about this is a simple JavaScript script that:

1. looks for mousemove & click events over a certain polygon
2. measures the amount of movement
3. changes half of the coordinates of the polygon (in order to have the effect of stretching) using this algorithm to define new coordinates: `x = x_movement`, `y = x_movement * Math.tan( 31 * (Math.PI/180) )`
4. polygons that are filled with a single colour are OK
5. polygons that are filled with a gradient are not, let me demonstrate:

**Visually**

[image: step_1]

So this is step one, no stretching has been done by the user.

[image: step_2]

This is where the problem happens. Since I don't know how should I change the `x1, y1` and `x2, y2` coordinates for the gradient, it just stays hanging in it's old position while the polygon has been stretched. The result is a shape that fails to sustain the illusion of depth.

[image: step_3]

The end result I'm looking for. And bare in mind that the gradient might have a completely random angle from the get go. In this end result, that I'm looking for, both the `x1, y1` and `x2, y2` coordinates of the gradient have been changed. **What algorithm should be used to calculate these positions?** I'm looking for a solution that is **completely blind to the angle of the gradient**.

Below is the SVG with all the appropriate coordinates that was used to generate these examples:

**Using SVG code**

Step1:

```
<!-- Step 1 -->
<linearGradient id="top_surface_1_gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="165.3425" y1="39.7002" x2="-49.991" y2="43.0337">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.6687" style="stop-color:#CCCCCC"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
</linearGradient>
<polygon id="top_surface_1" fill="url(#top_surface_1_gradient)" points="137.145,41.204 68.572,0 0,41.204 68.572,82.396"/>
```

Step 2

```
<!-- Step 2 --> 
<linearGradient id="top_surface_2_gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="250.0491" y1="233.8115" x2="23.7637" y2="237.3146">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.6687" style="stop-color:#CCCCCC"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
</linearGradient>
<polygon id="top_surface_2" fill="url(#top_surface_2_gradient)" points="205.788,215.557 137.215,174.354 0.078,256.629 68.649,297.823"/>
```

Step 3

```
<!-- Step 3 --> 
<linearGradient id="top_surface_3_gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="248.4543" y1="454.5225" x2="-75.535" y2="459.5381">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.6687" style="stop-color:#CCCCCC"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
</linearGradient>
<polygon id="top_surface_3" fill="url(#top_surface_3_gradient)" points="205.788,415.557 137.215,374.354 0.078,456.629 68.649,497.823"/>
```

I've spent countless hours developing solutions for this problem and I just couldn't get my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update: gradientTransform not quite**

Using the gradientTransform attribute and no x1,y1; x2,y2 coordinates for the gradient, we achieve results that fill the polygon in a way that is almost as needed (This solution can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqXx2/). The only place where the solution breaks is when the polygon is filled with a gradient that starts outside of the polygon and/or ends somewhere outside/inside. Let me illustrate:

This is what is achieved with the solution, that Duopixel is suggesting.
[image: step_4]

This is the usage case that is impossible to achieve using the solution mentioned above. I changed the colouring in order to visibly amplify the angle and gradient stops.
[image: step_5]

**SVG Code from the example**

Here's the code for the larger, correctly expanded group of polygons:

```
<g>
    <linearGradient id="surface_center_inside_bottom_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="167.7629" y1="634.5986" x2="-72.9039" y2="599.2647">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="0.8528" style="stop-color:#CCCCCC"/>
        <stop  offset="0.9954" style="stop-color:#CCCCCC"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <polygon id="surface_center_inside_bottom_9_" fill="url(#surface_center_inside_bottom_1_)" points="137.145,620.04 68.572,578.837 0,620.04 68.572,661.233"/>

    <linearGradient id="surface_right_inside_side_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="178.8889" y1="600.1787" x2="33.103" y2="517.9229">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="0.9816" style="stop-color:#A3A5A8"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <polygon id="surface_right_inside_side_3_" fill="url(#surface_right_inside_side_1_)" points="136.526,620.374 68.359,578.501 68.572,493.837 137.358,535.37"/>

    <linearGradient id="surface_right_inside_side_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="126.2664" y1="563.249" x2="-28.4" y2="621.916">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FF0000"/>
        <stop  offset="0.6698" style="stop-color:#00FFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FF0000"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <polygon id="surface_right_inside_side_5_" fill="url(#surface_right_inside_side_2_)" points="68.573,661.239 0,620.036 0,535.036 68.573,576.231"/>

    <linearGradient id="surface_center_outside_top_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="167.3728" y1="533.5059" x2="-47.9608" y2="536.8394">
        <stop  offset="0.0016" style="stop-color:#FF0000"/>
        <stop  offset="0.6735" style="stop-color:#00FFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FF0000"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <polygon id="surface_center_outside_top_3_" fill="url(#surface_center_outside_top_1_)" points="137.145,535.041 68.572,493.837 0,535.041 68.572,576.233"/>
</g>
```

And here's the SVG code for the smaller one, which I need to expand:

```
<g>
    <linearGradient id="surface_right_inside_side_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="273.4377" y1="319.251" x2="78.0696" y2="209.0197">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="0.9816" style="stop-color:#A3A5A8"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <polygon id="surface_right_inside_side_9_" fill="url(#surface_right_inside_side_4_)" points="205.112,366.797 136.945,324.924 137.157,156.261 205.731,197.464"/>

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="247.2952" y1="408.1992" x2="-103.1108" y2="356.7538">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="0.8528" style="stop-color:#CCCCCC"/>
        <stop  offset="0.9954" style="stop-color:#CCCCCC"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <polygon fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" points="205.731,366.465 137.157,325.262 0.021,407.536 68.592,448.729"/>

    <linearGradient id="surface_right_inside_side_7_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="160.3313" y1="296.623" x2="-52.0119" y2="377.1676">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FF0000"/>
        <stop  offset="0.6698" style="stop-color:#00FFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FF0000"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <polygon id="surface_right_inside_side_6_" fill="url(#surface_right_inside_side_7_)" points="68.532,448.767 0,407.497 0.021,238.536 68.592,279.729"/>

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="248.4749" y1="215.7417" x2="-75.5139" y2="220.7572">
        <stop  offset="0.0016" style="stop-color:#FF0000"/>
        <stop  offset="0.6735" style="stop-color:#00FFFF"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FF0000"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <polygon fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" points="205.731,197.464 137.157,156.261 68.592,197.333 0.021,238.536 68.592,279.729"/>
</g>
```

**@dignifiedquire take on this problem**

I've implemented @dignifiedquire suggested algo in a test site: [Here's the test link](http://9ball.me/svg_update/svg_version.php). I did the absolute to relative conversion on my own and it just shows the same result I would have normally adding the same polygon x and y change values to the gradient x and y. That is the main issue - how to translate those values into such value, that transform the gradient as in my examples above?

More help is needed.

Comment: Looks like a tricky problem.  However, I'm curious to know how PHP enters into the mix, as I don't see any PHP code at all, and only some brief mentions of javascript.  Could you expand on this?

Comment: It surely is a tricky one. Well I'm coding a dynamic solution (JS) as well as a server-side (PHP) one. Since I know and use PHP for that job, I picked it for this question. The same algorithm can be calculated using JS as well as PHP. So imagine that I'll store a certain configuration into a DB, say 'new_width' = 'x+100'. I'll need PHP to redraw the polygon using the same algo once the user reloads the page or sends a link to someone. I hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: A little off topic, but if you're using two languages and one of them supports talking to a server and the other supports running on a server then maybe you can cut down the amount of work you need to do by implementing the algorithm only on the server side and getting results from it client side with AJAX?

Comment: That would be the case if I wanted to store the current transformations (I.E. every single coordinate of every single graphical element) in a file or in a DB. But I plan on storing just the amount of movement to log the state. This will save a ton of space.

Comment: So I will be applying the change dynamically (with user mouse drag and so on), then storing only the changes in width/height/depth via AJAX. Once a reload happens I'll just recreate the same state from the w/h/d using the PHP version of the algo. I know my logic may seem a bit fuzzy, but in my mind it all makes perfect sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply transformations to gradients, this means you can do stuff such as `gradientTransform="rotate(45)`. This solves your rotation issue.

You should use relative units and set the userspace to `objectBoundingBox` so that the `x` and `y` values correspond to the dimensions of your polygon. Your svg would look like this.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <linearGradient id="top_surface_2_gradient" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientTransform="rotate(0 0.5 0.5)">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#000"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#fff"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <polygon id="top_surface_2" fill="url(#top_surface_2_gradient)" points="205.788,215.557 137.215,174.354 0.078,256.629 68.649,297.823"/>
</svg>​
```

You can test how it works on different sized polygons here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqXx2/

Comment: That is true, but only if there isn't a need for an angle. In my case there is a need for that. Your solution creates a 90 degree gradient, that starts with 0point of the polygon and ends with final_point of the polygon. I need to decouple the gradient completely from the polygon in the design phase while at the same time have an algo to dynamically change the gradients once deployed inside the interface. Thanks for the idea though :)

Comment: Even though my example and the graphics related to it display the gradient for the top surface (I.E it's fairly horizontal), there are other polygons that have gradients with 45, 60 and other wonky angles. Still an upvote.

Comment: In that case you're getting into some pretty tricky math, you would have to scale your elements with a transform matrix and then apply that transformation to your polygon path and your gradient. I've added percentages to my answer, perhaps you can work out a formula to convert from degrees to percentages.

Comment: I was actually thinking about that, but the math just got too hazy. And yeah one solution could possibly be converting the vector points into percentages, and I've tried this approach, but it just was beyond me.

Comment: I think I found the solution through `gradientTransform`. Answer updated.

Comment: Yes, it seems `gradientTransform` is definitely the right way to go. Since the angle is being replicated, it looks almost OK. There's only one thing left, what about positioning?_________ `[..--**], but how about ...[--**]*` ? It was my best attempt at ascii art...

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to interpret you ascii art :) Perhaps another image?

Comment: OK, I'll work on updating the question with the illustrations where this solution is not completely applicable. It'll be ready in about an hour. :)

Comment: I've posted updates to the question Duopixel, I hope that illustrates the problem more vividly.

Comment: I've added a bounty for this question, because I would really like that you'd expand on your answer with some type of an algo @Duopixel.

Comment: I got around to create each gradient using something similar to your solution and it worked out beautifully. So for now, answer accepted, but I think the complete solution is still out ahead :).

Answer (score 7):

**Update 3 Alternative Idea**

An alternative solution could be to calculate the percentage values based on the two end points of the gradient.
In this Picture you see the original polygon `abcd`, its bounding box `a'b'c'd'` and the gradient `g1g2`. The aim is now to calculate first the two points `g1` and `g2` in absolute values and then calculate the relative values of these two.

[image: bounding box]

I've derived an algorithm that does most of what I described but it fails short of calculating the intersection between the gradient and the bounding box. I have an idea on how to solve this problem but right now not the time to implement it, so I list the steps for that.
The basic idea is to test if the gradient intersects with one of the lines through the corners of the bounding box (`a'b'`,`b'c'`,`c'd'`,`d'a'`) and then test if the intersection is in on the edge in question. There are now two special cases that need handling.
  1. the gradient is vertical, this means its slope is infinity
  2. the side in question is vertical, again this means its slope is infinity
All other cases are easily solvable with basic math (two point form of a line, intersection of two lines).

*My algorithm*

```
_ = require('underscore')    

function intersectGradientWithPolygon(polygon, gradient){
  var sides = [
    ["a", "b"],
    ["b", "c"],
    ["c", "d"],
    ["d", "a"]
  ];

  var boundingBox = calculateBoundingBox(polygon);

  // intersect each side of the bounding box with the gradient
  var intersections = _.map(sides, function(side){
    var intersection = intersect(boundingBox[side[0]], boundingBox[side[1]], gradient.a, gradient.b);
    if(intersection){
      // calculate the percentages
      console.log(JSON.stringify(intersection));
      return calcPercentage(intersection, boundingBox);
    }
  });

  return intersections;

}


function Point(x,y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

function calcPercentage(intersection, boundingBox){
  var lengthX = (boundingBox.max.x - boundingBox.min.x),
      lengthY = (boundingBox.max.y - boundingBox.min.y),
      x = (intersection.x / lengthX) * 100,
      y = (intersection.y / lengthY) * 100;
}

function calculateBoundingBox(polygon){
  var xValues = _.pluck(polygon, 'x'),
      yValues = _.pluck(polygon, 'y'),
      maxX = _.max(xValues),
      maxY = _.max(yValues),
      minX = _.min(xValues),
      minY = _.min(yValues);


  return {
    "a": new Point(minX, maxY),
    "b": new Point(maxX, maxY),
    "c": new Point(maxX, minY),
    "d": new Point(minX, minY),
    "max": new Point(maxX, maxY),
    "min": new Point(minX, minY)
  };
}
// tests if the two lines a1, b1 and a2, b2 intersect and 
// returns the point of intersection if the do so
function intersect(a1, b1, a2, b2){

  var s = new Point( );

  // TODO
  // This is the part that is missing
  // one needs to implement what I described above at this point
  //

  if (isInIntervall(s.x, a1.x, b1.x) && isInIntervall(s.y, a2.y, b2.y)){
    return s;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

// test if a point is in the intervall [a,b]
function isInIntervall(point, a, b){
  return (point >= a) && (point <=b);
}
```

**Update 2**

> **Question:** Also how should the gradient coordinates change if the polygon is moved in space as a whole and not stretched.?
>
> **Answer:** You calculate the amount that you move one point of your polygon in x and y and move the points of the gradient the exact same amount.

I've now changed the algorithm to be based of scaling on one side of the polygon by absolute amount of units. 
I've also created an image to explain what the algorithm does

1. original polygon
2. scaled polygon by a scale factor determined by the inputs
3. move the polygon back to the original place

[image: explain]

**Updated 15.7.2012**
I've derived an algorithm based on the idea I proposed using transformation matrices for the transform. I hadn't time to test it but the code is running under node.js and should run in the browser if you include [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) and [sylvester](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/) (matrix operations) in your document.

**The Setup**

```
/* underscore for some helper methods
 * http:*http:*underscorejs.org
 */
_ = require("underscore");  

/* matrix operations
 * http:*sylvester.jcoglan.com
 */
require("sylvester");
```

**The inputs**

```
var gradient = {
  "a":{
    "x": 165.3425,
    "y": 39.7002
  },
  "b":{
    "x": -49.991,
    "y": 43.0337 
  }
};

var polygon = {
  "a": {
    "x": 137.145,
    "y": 41.204
  },
  "b": {
    "x": 68.572,
    "y": 0
  },
  "c": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 41.204
  },
  "d": {
    "x": 68.572,
    "y": 82.396
  }
};
// the scales are now absolute values in the same units as the coordinates
var scaleAbsX = 100;
var scaleAbsY = 100 * Math.tan( 62/2 * (Math.PI/180) );

// this describes the side that is scaled
var side = ["a", "b"];
```

**The Algorithm**

```
scalePolyWithGradient = function(polygon, gradient, scaleAbsX, scaleAbsY, side){
  // 1. Scale by factor: derive factor from input scaling and then translate into scaling matrix
  // 2. Apply scale to the gradient
  // 3. Translate both back 

  // create a scaling matrix based of the input scales

  // get the two points of the scaled side
  var point1 = polygon[side[0]],
      point2 = polygon[side[1]];
  // scale these points
  var scaledPoint1 = { "x": point1.x + scaleAbsX,
                       "y": point1.y + scaleAbsY },
      scaledPoint2 = { "x": point2.x + scaleAbsX,
                       "y": point2.y + scaleAbsY };

  // calculate the relative scales
  var scaleRelX = scaledPoint1.x / point1.x,
      scaleRelY = scaledPoint1.y / point1.y;

  // create the scale matrix
  var scaleMatrix = $M([ [scaleRelX, 0],
                     [0, scaleRelY] ]);


  // scale both the polygon and the gradient
  // we iterate so that the translation is done on every point
  var scale = function(point){
    // convert the point into a matrix
    point = $M([[point.x], 
                [point.y]]);

    // scale
    var newPoint = scaleMatrix.multiply(point);

    return { "x": newPoint.elements[0][0],
             "y": newPoint.elements[1][0]};
  };

  var newPolygon  = {},
      newGradient = {};

  _.each(polygon, function(point, key){
    newPolygon[key] = scale(point);
  });
  _.each(gradient, function(point, key){
    newGradient[key] = scale(point);
  });

  // calculate the translation to move them to the original position
  // and move them back

  // we know that the points to move to their original position are the
  // ones not in the scale side
  var sides = _.keys(polygon),                   // all possible sides
      movePoints = _.difference(sides, side),    // the points not used in the scale
      point = movePoints[0];                     // the first of these points

  // we use these points to create the translation
  var oldPoint = polygon[point],
      newPoint = newPolygon[point];
  var translateMatrix = $M([ [newPoint.x - oldPoint.x],
                             [newPoint.y - oldPoint.y] ]);

  var translate = function(point){
    // convert the point into a matrix
    point = $M([[point.x], 
                [point.y]]);

    // translate
    var newPoint = point.add(translateMatrix);

    return { "x": newPoint.elements[0][0],
             "y": newPoint.elements[1][0]};
  };
  // apply the translation
  _.each(newPolygon, function(point, key){
     newPolygon[key] = translate(point);
   });
   _.each(newGradient, function(point, key){
     newGradient[key] = translate(point);
   });

  // return the new coordinates
  return [newPolygon, newGradient];
};
// apply the algorithm
var newPolygon, newGradient = null;
var result = scalePolyWithGradient(polygon, gradient, scaleAbsX, scaleAbsY, side);
newPolygon = result[0];
newGradient = result[1];
```

**The result**

```
 newPolygon = { "a": {
                   "x": 178.2885,
                   "y":82.405 
                 },
                 "b": {
                   "x": 96.00089999999999,
                   "y": 20.598999999999997
                 },
                 "c": {
                   "x": 13.714500000000001,
                   "y": 82.405
                 },
                 "d": { 
                   "x": 96.00089999999999,
                   "y":144.19299999999998
                 }
               }
 newGradient = { "a": {
                   "x": 212.12550000000005,
                   "y":80.14930000000001
                 },
                 "b": {
                     "x": -46.274699999999996,
                     "y": 85.14955
                 }
               }
```

**Old Answer**

[The image is here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s130/sh/04be966e-143a-46f7-b92a-8cf5df2f656a/fb0edaeebe3cb6a2514da63ea846c8dd/res/fba6488f-3d14-4dc4-bb18-e57cd42805e1/scaling_concept-20120714-210224.png.jpg) because I can't upload images to stackoverflow (reputation is to low)

I abstracted the side of the polygon so we can focus on that. The left picture is before scaling. Now I've drawn the "whole" gradient to show what needs to be scaled. In order to figure out the needed coordinates one just scales the square of the gradient in the same proportion as the side of the polygon.

I know this image is without rotation but this method can be expanded to also incorporate this.

I can derive an algorithm for this stuff but haven't had the time to do so. So if this is what you want let me know and I will get to it tomorrow.

Comment: So there're a couple of questions regarding your proposed answer: 1. Is the polygon truly stretched only on the vertical axis 2. What would happen if the same model would be stretched on the horizontal axis 3. Proof of concept for a rotated gradient. If those 3 check out - significant praise your away! Eagerly waiting for your take on them and of course the algo. Upvote for the effort.

Comment: First impression looks great (I haven't been able to deploy it yet), I'll do the complete check up and get back at you today. Amazing work anyway!

Comment: Right @dignifiedquire I'm trying to adjust the gradient according to the amount of mouse movement. Could you point out how that relates to the scaleX and scaleY? Because I understand them as relative values, but how do I get absolute values, like scaleX += 10.

Comment: Yes scaleX is relative. I will update my answer with the possibility of scaling by absolute value when I come home.

Comment: Cool, just to make it easier, the values I supply is for example if I stretch the whole structure to the left by 100 px, then x_movement = 100, y_movement = x_movement * Math.tan( 62/2 * (Math.PI/180) ). Also how should the gradient coordinates change if the polygon is moved in space as a whole and not stretched. Thanks!

Comment: I really appreciate your effort @dignifiedquire , but I think you haven't tested your solution. Here's a link to your algo test [link](http://9ball.me/svg_update/svg_version.php) . I did the absolute to relative conversion on my own and it just shows the same result :/. And your update adding sides into the equation reduces the usefulness, because a polygon can have an unlimited amount of sides, not just four, so it's best not to have that in the algo.

Comment: I'm sorry for getting back to you just now. I think I missunderstood what you wanted. From what I got from your comment I think it should be possible fix my algorithm to do what you ask for. I will test it now and come back with the results.

Comment: That's great @dignifiedquire, I'll be eagerly waiting for your results!

Comment: I'm really sorry but it seems this problem is harder than I thought. I have some ideas on how to solve but the general approach I used in my solution is not going to work so easily. I guess one could do the transformation proposed by @Duopixel but when I looked into that there is the problem of intersection a line with a square, which is solvable but a lot of work because of the many edge cases that arrise. If you are interested in looking into that I can post my ideas.

Comment: Absolutely @dignifiedquire I'm interested!

Comment: Hey @dignifiedquire is there any way I could contact you? My email is wilde.morgan@gmail.com, what about yours?